# Invalid JSON was returned from the route. Perhaps an exception was thrown?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, jwt, lumen

I've been working on adding [JWT authentication](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) to my Lumen API. Please bare in mind I am new to Lumen, API design and TDD.  Before adding the authentication all of tests were passing. Honestly, everything seems to be working just fine except when I run phpunit.  What's difficult to understand is when I run the same test in postman I have no issues, however when I dump the response in phpunit i get `NULL`.  Perhaps a fresh set of eyes can help me out?

I've added the jwt.auth middleware to my restricted routes:

**routes.php**

```
// all other code omitted

$app->group([
  'prefix'     => $version . '/authors',
  'middleware' => 'jwt.auth',
  'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($app) {

  $app->get('/{id:[\d]+}', ['as' => 'authors.show', 'uses' => 'AuthorsController@show']);  

});
```

Part of my controller is as follows:

**AuthorsController.php**

```
class AuthorsController extends Controller
{

  // all other code omitted

  public function show($id)
  {
    return $this->item(Author::findOrFail($id), new AuthorTransformer());
  }

}
```

My model is as follows

**Author.php**

```
class Author extends Model
{
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable
 *
 * @var array
 */
  protected $fillable = ['name', 'biography', 'gender'];

  public function books()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
  }
}
```

And my Transformer is as follows:

**AuthorTransformer.php**

```
class AuthorTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{

  protected $availableIncludes = [
    'books',
  ];

  public function includeBooks(Author $author)
  {
    return $this->collection($author->books, new BookTransformer());
  }

  /**
   * Transform an author model
   *
   * @param Author $author
   * @return array
   */
  public function transform(Author $author)
  {
    return [
      'id'        => $author->id,
      'name'      => $author->name,
      'gender'    => $author->gender,
      'biography' => $author->biography,
      'created'   => $author->created_at->toIso8601String(),
      'updated'   => $author->created_at->toIso8601String(),
    ];
  }
}
```

And my tests are as follows:

**TestCase.php**

```
class TestCase extends Laravel\Lumen\Testing\TestCase
{

// all other code omitted

/**
 * Convenience method for creating a user
 *
 * @return $user
 */
  protected function userFactory()
  {

    $user = factory(\App\User::class, 1)->create(['password' => app('hash')->make('supersecret')]);

    return $user;
  }

/**
 * Convenience method for getting jwt and authenticating
 *
 * @return $body
 */
  protected function jwtAuthTest($method, $url, $body = [])
  {
    $user = $this->userFactory();

    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
    JWTAuth::setToken($token);
    $headers = array(
      "Accept"        => "application/json",
      "Authorization" => "Bearer " . $token,
    );

    switch ($method) {
      case 'get':
        $this->get($url, $body, $headers);
        break;
      case 'post':
        $this->post($url, $body, $headers);
        break;
      case 'put':
        $this->put($url, $body, $headers);
        break;
      case 'patch':
        $this->patch($url, $body, $headers);
        break;
      case 'delete':
        $this->delete($url, $body, $headers);
        break;
    }

    $data = json_decode($this->response->getContent(), true);

    return $data;
  }

}
```

**AuthorsControllerTest.php**

```
class AuthorsControllerTest extends TestCase
{

  // all other code omitted

/** @test **/
  public function show_should_fail_on_an_invalid_author()
  {
    $body = $this->jwtAuthTest('get', '/v1/authors/1234');

    // this works fine...
    $this->seeStatusCode(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);

    // NULL??
    var_dump($body);
  }
}
```

My response should be:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Not Found",
    "status": 404
  }
}
```

However I am getting `NULL`

When I test the same route with a valid token in Postman I get, which is what I'm expected in my tests:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Not Found",
    "status": 404
  }
}
```

Suddenly my route is returning null in phpunit tests.  I can't seem to figure out why?

My handler is as follows:

```
// all other code omitted
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
  /**
   * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $dontReport = [
    AuthorizationException::class,
    HttpException::class,
    ModelNotFoundException::class,
    ValidationException::class,
  ];

  /**
   * Report or log an exception.
   *
   * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
   *
   * @param  \Exception  $e
   * @return void
   */
  public function report(Exception $e)
  {
    parent::report($e);
  }

  /**
   * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \Exception  $e
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
   */
  public function render($request, Exception $e)
  {
    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
      $response = [
        'message' => (string) $e->getMessage(),
        'status'  => 400,
      ];

      if ($e instanceof HttpException) {
        $response['message'] = Response::$statusTexts[$e->getStatusCode()];
        $response['status']  = $e->getStatusCode();
      } else if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $response['message'] = Response::$statusTexts[Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND];
        $response['status']  = Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND;
      }

      if ($this->isDebugMode()) {
        $response['debug'] = [
          'exception' => get_class($e),
          'trace'     => $e->getTrace(),
        ];
      }

      return response()->json(['error' => $response], $response['status']);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);

  }

}
```

When my test fails I get:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\App\Http\Controllers\AuthorsControllerTest::show_should_fail_on_an_invalid_author
Invalid JSON was returned from the route. Perhaps an exception was thrown?
```

Please let me know if you need anything else and thank you in advance.

Source code: https://github.com/studio174/gscp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the `TestCase.php` there was a simple naming collision and invalid use of the get() method:

**TestCase.php**

```
/**
 * Convenience method for getting jwt and authenticating
 *
 * @return $body
 */
  protected function jwtAuthTest($method, $url, $body = [])
  {
    $user = $this->userFactory();

    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
    JWTAuth::setToken($token);
    $headers = array(
      "Accept"        => "application/json",
      "Authorization" => "Bearer " . $token,
    );

    switch ($method) {
      case 'get':
        // [FIX] removed $body from get request as this was overwriting my headers 
        // and causing my handler to return plain text instead of JSON
        $this->get($url,  $headers);
        break;
      case 'post':
        $this->post($url, $body, $headers);
        break;
      case 'put':
        $this->put($url, $body, $headers);
        break;
      case 'patch':
        $this->patch($url, $body, $headers);
        break;
      case 'delete':
        $this->delete($url, $body, $headers);
        break;
    }

    // [FIX] changed $body= json_decode($this->response->getContent(), true);
    $data = json_decode($this->response->getContent(), true);

    return $data;
  }
```